# How to make more than 1 nodes of mine connect each other?

Tags: nodes, peers

Lets say i have 5 `nodes` running.

each `node` is on its `dedicated server` and is upto date. and its connected to available `peers` on the network.

How can i make them to `connect each other` and not to `BAN` them, and connect them again in case of `bitcoind` restarts ?

so in case i plan to make star topology of nodes and use central node for RPC connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them to each other nodes bitcoin config file. If you want to connect to a specific node among others, use `addnode=IP:PORT` in your config. If you'd like to *only* connect to your own nodes and not other nodes on the network, you can use `connect` instead of `addnode`, but of course you should have at least one outgoing connection to get blocks, etc :)